# cPanel modified htaccess file stops access of session variables over multiple pages

Tags: php, authentication, .htaccess, session-variables

In my webpage if a user logs in then the login session variables are not available if the user moves to other pages under the same domain.  Login information is processed with login.php, which redirects to page2.php. Session variables of user information are available in login.php but not in page2.php. Page2.php gives the following output:
*User login id not found on page2*

The problem started recently as cPanel has auto-edited the htaccess file to add the following line:

```
        <IfModule mime_module>
          AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
        </IfModule>
```

If I remove this line from htaccess then the code runs fine and page2.php gives the following output:
*User login id found on page2, userid=45*

The codes of login.php, page.php and htaccess are shown below.
I do not want to remove the cPanel added lines from htaccess as this can be added again. The MultiPHP Manager in cPanel shows: ea-php74.
MIME Types shows:
MIME types: application/x-httpd-ea-php74, extension: .php .php7 .phtml

**Question**: How can I get the login session variables on page2.php?

Login.php

```
        <?php 
        session_start();
        $myUsername = $_POST['FormUsername'];
        $myPassword = md5($_POST['FormPassword']);'
        //Connect to database
        //Find the userid ($myUserId) from database for $myUsername
        $_SESSION['SessionUserId'] = $myUserId;
        header("Location: https://www.example.com/test1/page2.php");
        ?>
```

page2.php:

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <?php session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['SessionUserId'])) {   
           $thisUserId = $_SESSION['SessionUserId'];
           echo "User login id found on page2, userid=$thisUserId  <br/>";
        } else {    
           echo "User login id not found on page2 <br/>";    
        } ?> </html>
```

Htaccess file:

```
        ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/index\.(php|html)\ HTTP [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*)index\.(php|html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
        Options 6-Indexes
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
        AuthUserFile /Het/.htpasswd
        # php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
        # Set the ea-php74 package as the default PHP programming language.
        <IfModule mime_module>
        AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
        </IfModule>
        # php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: Can't really explain why this line should stop your sessions from working. If you remove it (or comment it out), which PHP version are your scripts executing with then? (Use `phpinfo()` to check.)

Comment: `Options 6-Indexes` looks like it should cause an error though, that `6-` isn't part of any syntax/option value I know. And the purpose of the first RewriteCond/RewriteRule combo is unclear as well.

Comment: Hi CBroe, Many thanks. I just checked and found that the PHP version of my script is 7.0.33. Could be the problem?

Comment: Unlikely to be directly linked to the specific minor PHP version; probably more likely that some of the session-cookie related settings differ, so I would start by comparing those.

Comment: "that `6-` isn't part of any syntax/option value" - Only the `6` is in error. The `-` should not be removed as that would disable the mod_rewrite directives (since it would remove the `FollowSymLinks` option). "the first RewriteCond/RewriteRule combo is unclear" - That rule simply removes `index.php` (or `index.html`) from the end of the URL (although is arguably over complex if these are the only rules being used). `AuthUserFile` is also superfluous here (and looks invalid anyway). @CBroe

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE HTML><?php session_start();` - You appear to have _output_ before your call to `session_start()`?!

Comment: Hi CBroe and MrWhite, thanks. The htacess line 'Options 6-Indexes' does not actually have '6'. While copy/pasting I must have inadvertently typed 6. Sorry about it. However, I cannot find any other error. Once again, if I remove the added line in htaccess (added by cPanel) then everything works fine. I am exploring now with the session cookie settings. Is there anything else that I can check? I am stuck on this issue. thanks in advance.